# Mongoose add to array of nested array if exists create otherwise

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

i'm trying to accomplish the following in mongoose:

Say i have the following collection

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "111"
    },
    "email": "xxx@mail.com",
    "givenName": "xxx",
    "familyName": "xxx",
    "favoriteProducts": [{
        "soldTo": "33040404",
        "skus": ["W0541", "W2402"]
    }, {
        "soldTo": "1223",
        "skus": ["12334"]
    }]
}
```

i want to  be able to add a sku to the favorite products array based on soldTo and _id.
When doing this there are two possible scenarios.

a. There is already an object in favoriteProducts with the given soldTo in which case the sku is simply added to the array.(for example add sku '12300' to soldTo '1223' for id '111')

b. There is no object with the given soldTo yet in which case this object need to be created with the given sku and soldTo. (for example add sku '123' to soldTo '321' for id '111')

so far i've done this but i feel like there is a way to do it in one query instead.

```js
 private async test() {
    const soldTo = '1223';
    const sku = '12300';
    const id = '111';
    const hasFavoriteForSoldTo = await userModel.exists({
      _id: id,
      'favoriteProducts.soldTo': soldTo,
    });

    if (!hasFavoriteForSoldTo) {
      await userModel
        .updateOne(
          {
            _id: id,
          },
          { $addToSet: { favoriteProducts: { skus: [sku], soldTo } } },
        )
        .exec();
    } else {
      await userModel
        .updateOne(
          {
            _id: id,
            'favoriteProducts.soldTo': soldTo,
          },
          { $addToSet: { 'favoriteProducts.$.skus': sku } }
        )
        .exec();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)

Check out mongo play ground below. Not sure you want **Output 1** or **Output 2**.

**Output 1**

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: { "$oid": "111222333444555666777888" }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      favoriteProducts: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $in: [ "1223", "$favoriteProducts.soldTo" ] },
          then: {
            $map: {
              input: "$favoriteProducts",
              as: "f",
              in: {
                $cond: {
                  if: { $eq: [ "1223", "$$f.soldTo" ] },
                  then: { $mergeObjects: [ "$$f", { skus: [ "12300" ] } ] },
                  else: "$$f"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          else: {
            $concatArrays: [ "$favoriteProducts", [ { skus: [ "12300" ], soldTo: "1223" } ] ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oDFygzrk3LY)

---

**Output 2**

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: { "$oid": "111222333444555666777888" }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      favoriteProducts: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $in: [ "1223", "$favoriteProducts.soldTo" ] },
          then: {
            $map: {
              input: "$favoriteProducts",
              as: "f",
              in: {
                $cond: {
                  if: { $eq: [ "1223", "$$f.soldTo" ] },
                  then: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$f",
                      { skus: { $concatArrays: [ [ "12300" ], "$$f.skus" ] } }
                    ]
                  },
                  else: "$$f"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          else: {
            $concatArrays: [ "$favoriteProducts", [ { skus: [ "12300" ], soldTo: "1223" } ] ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fQ0Q52oct-m)

Comment: output 2 is perfect thanks!